# How to compile and run a C++ project with a Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I needed a library for my project that would cover CANFIS functionalities and [Fuzzylitex](https://github.com/sguazt/fuzzylitex) does that. But the problem is, I don't know how to build this project? I am familiar with cmake files but this project has Makefile and I cannot work with it? I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Please search online for "how to use make?", it should be trivial to find at least some info.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I searched and found tutorials about making projects with Makefile! then how should I open a project with Makefile?

Comment: Unlike cmake, makefiles are not cross platform, and the one you are trying to use appears to be for Linux systems, not Windows systems. So you probably should be looking at WSL so you can get Linux onto your Windows box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I found out about the difference between Makefile and Cmake files. The tool that can be used to make a project with Makefile in Visual Studio, is [NMAKE.EXE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=msvc-160). It is built in for Visual Studio. All you need to do is to open the visual studio command prompt (tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt) and go to the directory of the Makefile and type "nmake" and press enter. The problem just begins here! There is a good chance that you will get errors. Anyway, this is the solution to my problem. Also, [this](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/makefiles-windows/) is a good tutorial on using NMAKE.